# Use OpenXML to replace text in DOCX file - strange content

Tags: c#, docx, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to use the OpenXML SDK and the samples on Microsoft's pages to replace placeholders with real content in Word documents.

It used to work as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508261.aspx), but after editing the template file in Word adding headers and footers it stopped working. I wondered why and some debugging showed me this:

[image]

Which is the content of `texts` in this piece of code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DocumentFile, true))
{
    var texts = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>().ToList();
}
```

So what I see here is that the body of the document is "fragmented", even though in Word the content looks like this:

[image]

Can somebody tell me how I can get around this?

---

I have been asked what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I want to replace user defined "placeholders" with real content. I want to treat the Word document like a template. The placeholders can be anything. In my above example they look like `{var:Template1}`, but that's just something I'm playing with. It could basically be *any* word.

So for example if the document contains the following paragraph:

> Do *not* use the name **USER_NAME**

The user should be able to replace the `USER_NAME` placeholder with the word `admin` for example, keeping the formatting intact. The result should be

> Do *not* use the name **admin**

The problem I see with working on paragraph level, concatenating the content and *then* replacing the content of the paragraph, I fear I'm losing the formatting that should be kept as in

> Do not use the name admin

Comment: It's always going to be a bit like this if you get the text runs, the text runs can be individual formatted (e.g. if you underline a single character in a paragraph). Why don't you get the text at the paragraph level instead? e.g. `Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().`

Comment: @NickDewitt Well, if I do that, wouldn't I lose other formatting applied to other text in that paragraph?

Comment: well no, the text elements will still be inside the paragraph, there is formatting at both the paragraph and text run level. If you take the node text from the paragraph or text-run level it's going to lose it's formatting anyway. What are you trying to achieve, e.g. what are you going to do with the elements after you extract them?

Comment: If you are trying to replace the `{var:Template1}` and `{var:Template2}`, looking for a match on the paragraph level will be suitable, then swap out the containing paragraph for the content you are inserting.

Comment: @NickDewitt I'm trying to replace placeholders with real values. The user can decide how placeholders are formatted. In my example it's something like `{var:Template1}`, but it could also be `USER_NAME`. Basically it's some sort of text search & replace. I'm going to edit my question in that respect.

Comment: when you are searching for the string, you aren't interested in formatting, so get a list of paragraphs and you can search on the 'node text' value to find the paragraph that equals or contains the text you want, when you find it you need to replace the text inside that node to retain it's formatting. I think you might be better off with some code that 'fixes' your original template and combines consecutive text runs with matching properties, I can help you with that if it's easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various things can fragment text runs. Most frequently proofing markup (as apparently is the case here, where there are "squigglies") or rsid (used to compare documents and track who edited what, when), as well as the "Go back" bookmark Word sets in the background. These become readily apparent if you view the underlying WordOpenXML (using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool, for example) in the document.xml "part".

It usually helps to go an element level "higher". In this case, get the list of Paragraph descendants and from there get all the Text descendants and concatenate their InnerText.

Comment: Thanks. If I get the text for the entire paragraph, I'd have to replace my keyword with the desired value and then set the text for the paragraph, right? Wouldn't that mean that I lose all other formatting for that paragraph? What I'd really like to achieve is the same thing that happens when I use the "Search & Replace" function in Word. Just replace some text, keeping other formatting intact.

Comment: You cannot get a complete answer if you do not provide complete information in your question. What keyword? What formatting? What else have you not mentioned? Give us a real example. And no, there's no SIMPLE way using Open XML to Find/Replace the way Word exposes to the user and its APIs. Behind the scenes, Word is having to deal with the same situation. When you work with Open XML you're working at a much more basic level, which means more work...

Comment: I'm giving you all the information there is. I have a Word document, there's text in it, in which I want to replace certain words by other words like the Search & Replace function does in Word. The example I've given is the actual content of the Word document (screenshot) and the exact code that returns the text parts of the document. There's nothing else I haven't mentioned. I'm aware of the fact that using OpenXML is on a more basic level than VSTO, but I'd have expected a bit more abstraction...

Comment: You have to decide how to handle formatting "conflicts". It seems to me that, up until now, you haven't had to worry about formatting at a character level (such as bold, italics) because you'd have run into the problem before this. As Nick mentioned, formatting applied at the paragraph level won't be affected by picking up the text content per paragraph. You might be able to visualize this better if you look at the raw XML code in document.xml using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool.

Comment: If you get all the text in the Paragraph, make the replacement, REMOVE all current Runs, RunProperties and Text nodes then write in a new Run with Text it won't affect paragraph formatting.

Comment: I do know that kind of structure. It's not very different from WPF `FlowDocuments`, really and I'm pretty aware of *why* this is happening. I also do know what it looks like on XML level. I'd just not have expected things like proofing markup and stuff to have influence on this. As for paragraph formatting please take a look at the edit I've made to the question. Guess I'll have to live with having to compare the find position with the runs so I can determine the runs I have to concatenate/replace. As I said, I'd hoped there'd be some sort of higher level way.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, because it was the first one and at least pointed me to a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

OpenXML is indeed fragmenting your text:

I created a [library](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater) that does exactly this : render a word template with the values from a JSON.

From the [documenation of docxtemplater](http://docxtemplater.readthedocs.org/en/latest/goals.html#why-you-should-use-a-library-for-this) :

> ## Why you should use a library for this
>
> Docx is a zipped format that contains some xml. If you want to build a simple replace {tag} by value system, it can already become complicated, because the {tag} is internally separated into `<w:t>{</w:t><w:t>tag</w:t><w:t>}</w:t>`. If you want to embed loops to iterate over an array, it becomes a real hassle.

The library basically will do the following to keep formatting :

If the text is :

```
<w:t>Hello</w:t>
<w:t>{name</w:t>
<w:t>} !</w:t>
<w:t>How are you ?</w:t>
```

The result would be :

```
<w:t>Hello</w:t>
<w:t>John !</w:t>
<w:t>How are you ?</w:t>
```

You also have to replace the tag by `<w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">` to ensure that the space is not stripped out if they is any in your variables.